# How to store a ratio in a single variable and read it back in C#

Tags: c#

Let's say I have a system that must store how many people voted on fighter A and how many on fighter B.

Let's say ratio is 200:1

How can I store that value in a single variable, instead of storing both values (number of voters on A and number of voters on B) in two variables.

How you would do that?

Comment: Is the ratio always X:1, in that case no reason to save the last figure, only save X, or 200 in this case. If the last figure will be anything else than 1, please give an example.

Comment: A better question is why would you want to do that? What is wrong with storing it in two variables? I can think of plenty of reasons why you shouldn't do that...

Comment: The ratio can be X:Y where X & Y can have any positive value and never zero.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From the way that the question is worded this might not be the answer you are looking for, but the easiest way is to use a struct:

```
struct Ratio
{
    public Ratio(int a, int b)
    {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }

    public int a = 1;
    public int b = 1;
}
```

You will almost certainly want to use properties instead of fields and you will probably also want to overload `==` and `!=`, something like:

```
public static bool operator ==(Ratio x, Ratio y)
{
    if (x.b == 0 || y.b == 0)
        return x.a == y.a;
    // There is some debate on the most efficient / accurate way of doing the following
    // (see the comments), however you get the idea! :-)
    return (x.a * y.b) == (x.b / y.a);
}

public static bool operator !=(Ratio x, Ratio y)
{
    return !(x == y);
}

public override string ToString()
{
    return string.Format("{0}:{1}", this.a, this.b);
}
```

Comment: Actually, for a reliable comparison (I mean `==` operator) you should use multiplication instead of integer division, i.e.: `return (x.a * y.b) == (x.b * y.a);`

Comment: The == operator has a bug in it.  If x.a is 1, y.a is 2 and both b's are 3, the integer division will yield 0 for both ratios.

Comment: @JeremyP: that's exaclty what I tried to point out, in my first comment ;)

Comment: @digEMall: sorry, missed your first comment.  Although technically, your answer has a chance of integer overflow. I'd reduce the numbers to being coprime in the constructor and then just compare the a's and b's

Comment: @JeremyP: yes, you're right that would be the correct way. But reducing a fraction could be computationally expensive, so if you suppose not to have so big values you can still use my simple method (perhaps using int64 to give more space to the multiplication)

Comment: @Kragen: First of all I want to precise that in term of accuracy both Jeremy method and mine are completely equal. Anyway, I will partially withdraw my previous statement about performance, because Euclidean Algorithm (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm#Implementations) can find the Greatest Common Divisor in few iterations (depending by the numbers) and so it is not much more expensive. I still think multiplication method would be faster in general, but maybe could be very useful to have ratio represented as fraction in lowest terms.

Comment: So for example one can reduce the fraction in the constructor, an therefore be sure that equal ratios will have equal a and b.

Answer (score 4):

A ratio is, by definition, the result of dividing two numbers. Therefore, just do that division and store the result in a `double`:

```
double ratio = (double)a/b;
```

Comment: A ratio is really not the result of diving two numbers... what about when the ratio is 1:0?

Comment: If the ratio is 1:0, you can use an error code, such as -1 and you can use -2 as an error code for 0:0. However, there is another problem, because in programming (x / y) * y = x is not always true, because computers can't have a 100% precisity in number dividing. For example 1 / 3 = 0.333333333333333...333333333... in reality, but  the computers don't store that precisely. For example the computer stores 0.333333. This way, (1 / 3) * 3 = 0.333333 * 3 = 0.999999 != 1. This is why we must consider division imprecise for a ratio even if we have an error code for 1/0 and 0/0.

Comment: +1, Timwi. Still, a ratio holds more information than the result of the division.

Comment: It depends on what the ratio is being used for as to whether the precision of the calculation is likely to be a problem. For example if as well as storing the ratio (lets say 1/3) you are storing the number of voters (lets say 400) then when you are workign otu teh voters on each side you know its an integer so if you get voters of 100.00001 and 299.9999 or similar then you can jsut round without a problem. It really depends on the context of usage so its not for us to say whether it is sufficient or not. I'd personally think it was in most cases.

Comment: Despite the fact that Pierre has stated that 1:0 can't happen in this case, I still feel the need to mindlessly argue my point! :-) Mathematically speaking a ratio is "a relationship between two numbers of the same kind" (from Wikipedia) - the two numbers can be fractions, zero, negative - they can even be complex, so 1:0 and 0:0 definitely *are* ratios.

Answer (score 4):

string ratio="200:1"; // simple :)

Comment: Brillant! As a plus side - this can be saved in a single db column :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use struct like this:

```
struct Ratio
{
    public void VoteA()
    {
        A++;
    }

    public void VoteB()
    {
        B++;
    }

    public int A { get; private set; }
    public int B { get; private set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return A + ":" + B;
    }
}
```

It's enough to implement voting in case if you have only two options available. Otherwise you should implement constructor accepting number of options, data structure to store number of votes, methods for voting or index operator. 
If you need the ratio for some integral math applications you might want to implement GCD method.

Answer (score 1):

It think you need to do it in a `string` for a single variable

```
string s=string.Format("{0}:{1}", 3, 5);
```

Answer (score 1):

Array? `int[] ratio = new int[2]` is much slimmer than a whole struct/class for 2 variables. Though if you want to add helper methods to it, a struct is the way to go.

Comment: I wouldn't say that its *much* slimmer - the runtime memory is use the same with a struct.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you can use doubles.

Ratio     Number

1:200     1.200

200:1     200:1

0:1       0.1

1:0       1.0

0:0       0.0

It's easy to use.

```
firstNumber = (int)Number;
secondNumber = Number - firstNumber;
```

Comment: So 1:20 == 1:200? According to your suggestion both are stored as 1.2